# What's the difference between L1 and L2 networks?

Tags: solidity, polygon

I know there are some networks like polygon. I would like to understand the difference between L1 and L2 and if I have ether in one network can it be transferred to others?

Answer (score 0):

Layer 1 is the orginial layer of the blockchain like Eth
And layer 2 is built on layer 1, like polygon.

Kind regards,
Max

Answer (score 0):

> between L1 and L2 and if I have ether in one network can it be transferred to others?

L2 chain cannot exist without L1: essentially it relies on the L1 chain for its chain security. In theory, you should always be able to withdraw back from L2 chain to its original L1 chain, even though the L2 chain would fail somehow. However, if L1 fails then all L2 chains on the top fail as well.

L2s trade-off cost and speed for complexity: Doing transactions on L2 writes less data to its parent chain L1, as doing transactions directly on L1, using compressed proofs or checkpoints or similar.

Example of L2s: Arbitrum on Ethereum, Optimism on Ethereum.

Example of not L2s: Polygon, BNB Smart chain, Avalanche. These are independent. Even if Ethereum fails Polygon will keep running.